# Eclipse out of memory when trying to launch Selendroid application

Tags: android, eclipse, out-of-memory, selendroid

I'm trying to implement an app following [these instructions from Selendroid official website](http://selendroid.io/setup.html) but I am not able to make it work. When I try to launch my app, Eclipse gets stucked in Launching 100% and I have to wait like 5-10 minutes until I can get it back. Here is the error: [image]

If I take a look at Eclipse's Console I can see A BUNCH of errors similar to these:

```
[2014-12-26 00:53:35 - QualE] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.bcel.generic.InstructionList$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-26 00:53:57 - QualE] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.bcel.generic.Type$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-26 00:54:02 - QualE] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.bcel.util.ClassPath$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-26 00:54:02 - QualE] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.bcel.util.ClassPath$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-26 00:54:02 - QualE] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.bcel.util.ClassPath$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-12-26 00:59:20 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
[2014-12-26 00:59:20 - QualE] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Open **eclipse.ini** file in your eclipse downloaded folder and update below args.

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: I think the problem is not with Eclipse but with an environment configuration regarding to Selendroid